# Import database into magento

Tags: database, magento, import

I want to import tecdoc database into magento, but until now without success. I have tecdoc in msql format and can export it into csv and xml. My problem is how to import the products to keep the schema of the database.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me, where did you find MySQL TecDoc database? I'm searching for PHP parser, because i have data only in text files, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if you still need an answer to your question or if you have figured it out already. One thing I should say in advance, TECDOC and Magento are totally different structures, you will need to be more clear on your question. What I am working on at this moment is some complex queries that will produce the specific products and categories. And use Perl to insert it into Magento

Comment: Until now I didn't manage to import the products, My problem is that I don't know how to mass import I can export the data in any format you need ( here I mean how the table to look and what info to contain ).  If you found a solution let me know , maybe we can exchange info.

Comment: If you are capable of extracting the data from your own MySQL version of TecDoc, that is a great starter already, for it is e very complex beast. Then the problem boils down to two steps: (1) generate the proper CSV file (2) importing the data into Magento... What have you done so far?

Comment: I am stuck at importing the data in magento, just trying to find a proper importer into the database of magento and until now without luck, Have to find somethign good because the files are big enought to stuck the script.

Comment: 'stuck' ? as in "can't import even one single" for that is the hardest part, or stuck "because the amount of data", the last is a bit tedious.

Answer (score 1):

Well I suspect that my post might be out of the topic, but here is a magento extension, which collects the Tecdoc data from Soap API and display the results in real time.

http://www.nimble3.com/car-parts-supplier-website-development-using-hpi-tecdoc/

demo: http://nimble3.com/demo/tecgento/template-2/car-parts.html